# is it possible for avassetwriter to output to memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, video, h.264, avassetwriter

I would like to write an iphone app that continuously capture video, h.264 encode them in 10 seconds interval and upload to a storage server.  This can be done with avassetwriter, and I can keep on deleting the old files as I create new ones.  However, as flash memory have a limited write cycles, this scheme will destroy the flash after a few thousand write cycles through the flash.  Is there a way to redirect avassetwriter to memory, or create a ram drive on the iphone?

Thanks!

Comment: "However, as flash memory have a limited write cycles, this scheme will destroy the flash after a few thousand write cycles through the flash. " I'm pretty sure memory management doesn't work this way as there are a lot of processes that create and overwrite temp files. what you say would be true if you constantly wrote to the same area, but it sheldom gets implemented that way in a os.

Comment: have you found a way to do that?

Comment: I am trying to implement the same thing. I have a almost-working solution where I switch between two AVAssetWriters.I run in to problems since I need to buffer audio samples when switching between the writers. I create a copy of the sampleBuffer using CMSampleBufferCreateCopy.

user1244109 - any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes avassetwriter is the only way to get to the hardware decoder. and simply reading back the file while its written doesn't give you the moov atoms so avfoundation or mpmediaplayer based players won't be able to read it back. you only have a couple choices , periodically stop the asassetwriter and write to the file on a background thread, effectively segmenting your movie into smaller complete files. or you could deal with the  incomplete mp4 on the server side, you will have to decode the raw nalu's and recreate the missing moov atoms. If your using ffmpeg mov.c is source to look at. This is also were an incomplete mp4 file would fail.

Comment: Please see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851481/http-live-streaming-server-on-iphone/13889048#13889048